# If condition in Kendo UI grid template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

```
field: 'Status' ,
         width: '70px' , 
         template: "#if(Status == 'On Request') {#<div class='redAndBold'>#:Status</div>#}#"
```

I have a kendo UI grid where the "Status" is being filled in from the javascript file. The Status in the model can be "On Request", and what I want is: if it is "On Request", add a class to it, "redAndBold". The syntax in this particular example gives a "user is not defined" error.

Could anyone give me some pointers on how to correctly do this?

Comment: A missing `#` after `Status`: `#:Status#`

Answer (score 6):

The kendo.templates depend on #=fieldName# or #:fieldName#. In the current case, there is a missing closing "#" after 'Status'. The templates are evaluated with the value of the field when bound to a data item during initialization. For executing JavaScript logic use only "#JS logic goes here#". Further information can be found here [Kendo UI templates](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview#template-syntax).

To avoid confusion of the template syntax, plain JavaScript function can be used instead:

```
template: "#=templateFunc(data)#"

// JS handler
function templateFunc(dataItem){
    if(dataItem.Status== 'On Request') {
        return "<div class='redAndBold'>"+dataItem.Status+"</div>";
    } else{
        return dataItem.Status;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are missing a # after Status. When you inject the value of a variable it needs a # before and after. If you split the template code over several lines whilst you write it, it can be easier to get it right.

```
#if(Status == 'On Request') {#
<div class='redAndBold'>
#:Status#
</div>
#}#
```

A good check is to count the number of # symbols in your template. It should always be an even number.

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution used was actually different, I added encoded: false; to the column and did the work in the javascript. That's actually good to know however to count the # symbols. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

As many people pointed out, you're missing a pound sign. I would like to point out that you can set the template as a function that returns a string. I generally do this because there are nuances with the string template such as escaping pound signs among other things:

```js
field: 'Status',
width: '70px', 
template: function(dataItem) {
  var div = $('<div />');
  if (dataItem.Status === 'On Request') {
    div.addClass('redAndBold');
  }
  return div.prop('outerHTML');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use function for a template :

```
}, {
                field: "TrackingNumber",
                title: "@T("Admin.Orders.Shipments.TrackingNumber")",
            }, {
                field: "ShippingMethodName",
                title: "@T("Admin.Orders.Shipments.ShippingMethodName")",
                template:function(dataItem) {
                        var template;
                        var ShippingMethodPluginName = dataItem.ShippingMethodPluginName;
                        var IsReferanceActive = dataItem.IsReferanceActive;
                        var ShippingMethodName = dataItem.ShippingMethodName;
                        var CargoReferanceNo = dataItem.CargoReferanceNo;
                        var ShipmentStatusId = dataItem.ShipmentStatusId;
                        if (ShipmentStatusId == 7) {
                            return "<div align='center'><label class='label-control'><b style='color:red'>Sipariş İptal Edildi<b></label></div>";
                        } else {
                            if (ShippingMethodPluginName == "Shipping.ArasCargo" || ShippingMethodPluginName == "Shipping.ArasCargoMP") {
                                template =
                                    "<div align='center'><img src = '/content/images/aras-kargo-logo.png' width = '80' height = '40'/> <label class='label-control'><b>Delopi Aras Kargo Kodu<b></label>";
                                if (IsReferanceActive) {
                                    template =
                                        template +
                                        "<label class='label-control'><b style='color:red; font-size:20px'>"+CargoReferanceNo+"<b></label></div>"; 
                                }
                                return template;
                            }
```